# Cognito is staying logged in as one user even if in incognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cognito

I've basically followed this medium article to set up cognito in Node.JS. I used express for the UI: https://medium.com/@prasadjay/amazon-cognito-user-pools-in-nodejs-as-fast-as-possible-22d586c5c8ec

However, only one user can be logged in for the whole application. And that user becomes logged in on every browser and IP address. So the code isn't treating everyone as a separate user.

I tried putting the userPool in every function as shown below, as before it was a constant at the top of the JS file. However that did not do anything.

Here are the main functions:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if(cognitoUser === null) {
        res.render('index')
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    }


});

app.get('/dashboard',  (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser != null) {
        cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
            if (err) {
                req.flash('error_msg', err.message)
                res.redirect('/');
            }
            if (session.isValid()) {
                cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        req.flash('error_msg', err.message)
                        res.redirect('/');
                    }
                   let token = session['idToken']['jwtToken'];
                   ValidateToken(token);
                   res.render('dashboard', {name: result[2].getValue(), email: result[3].getValue()})

                });
            }

        });

    }
    else {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'You are not logged in...')
        res.redirect('/');
    }


})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let username = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;

    let authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
        Username : username,
        Password : password,
    });

    let userData = {
        Username : username,
        Pool : userPool
    };

    let cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            // console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            // console.log('id token + ' + result.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
            // console.log('refresh token + ' + result.getRefreshToken().getToken());
            req.flash('success_msg', 'Logged in');
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            req.flash('success_msg', err.message);
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
            console.log(err);
        },

    });

})

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if(cognitoUser === null) {
        res.render('register')
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    }


})


app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let username = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let personalname = req.body.name;

    let attributeList = [];

    let dataEmail = {
        Name : 'email',
        Value : username, //get from form field
    };

    let dataPersonalName = {
        Name : 'name',
        Value : personalname, //get from form field
    };

    let attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
    let attributePersonalName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPersonalName);


    attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    attributeList.push(attributePersonalName);

    userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error_msg', err.message);
            res.redirect('/register');
            return;
        }
        res.render('verify', {user: result.user.getUsername()})
    });



})

app.post('/activation-code', (req, res) => {
    let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    let email = req.body.username;
    let activation_code = req.body.activation_code;

    let userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: userPool
    };

    let cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

    // signing up
    cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(activation_code, false, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            req.flash('error_msg', error.message)
            res.render('verify', {user: email})
        }
        else {
           req.flash('success_msg', 'You have successfully verified your email. You can now log in.')
           res.redirect('/')
        }
    });
})
```

I expect it to treat one browser session as one user, like a regular sign up. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you authenticating the user against the user pool?

Comment: Yes, I solved it after realising I wasn't writing any session management code. I used this repo for reference when implementing session management https://github.com/thoughtAddict/cognito-express-barebones